# for loop skips a character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop in python and it skipped the last character in the string, I tried printing the variable like so:
`for i in "125": print (i)`
and it didnt print the 5, here's my script:

```
    OctalBinary1 = {
          "0" : "000",
          "1" : "001",
          "2" : "010",
          "3" : "011",
          "4" : "100",
          "5" : "101",
          "6" : "110",
          "7" : "111"
}
def toBinaryOctal(x):
          counter = 0
          sum_var = ""
          fin_var = ""
          for i in x:
                    counter += 1
                    sum_var += str(i)
                    if (counter != 3):
                               for x , y in OctalBinary1.items():
                                        if x == sum_var:

                                                  fin_var += OctalBinary1[x]
                                                  sum_var = ""
                                        else:
                                             print ("Did not find a match")
                                             print (i)

          return fin_var




print (toBinaryOctal("125"))
```

Comment: what's wrong with `bin(125)` ?

Comment: I'm just trying to do that myself

Comment: as a part of my school homework

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in x:
    counter += 1
    sum_var += str(i)

    if (counter != 3):
```

When the for loop reaches `"5"` counter will be 3 at line `if (counter != 3)`, so it will break the loop right after. That's why you don't get `"5"` output.